# Why can't we solve a system of equations with three equations containing two variables each?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am in High School Pre-Calculus and my teacher was showing us three equation systems with three variables. I asked if it was possible to solve systems with two variables each and three equations and he said that was not possible. I was wondering why? Thank you.

Comment: Excepting degenerate cases, *two* equations in two variables determines the values of the variables uniquely. So if you throw in an arbitrary *third* equation involving those variables, chances are it won't be satisfied. Said differently, such a system is typically *overdetermined* (too many conditions on too few variables to allow a solution to exist). That said, you can of course construct specific examples where there is a solution, or even infinitely many solutions, but in those cases the equations are redundant.

Comment: @MPW I dont know exactly what you mean when you say "chances are it will be satisfied". Just because the chances are low it doesnt mean you shouldnt try and solve it right? Even if there is no solution, at least you can write "No Solution".

Comment: can you show us these systems?

Comment: An overdetermined system say or may not have a solution. In the "general" case, it does not. However, there are exceptions. The system $$\begin{cases}x-y=0\\2x-2y=0\\3x-3y=0\end{cases}$$ of three equations in two variables has an infinite number of solutions. They are precisely the pairs $(t,t)$ for each value of $t$. Of course, you can see that these equations are really redundant. But you can produce a system with no solution easily by changing the RHS of the last two equations to (say) $1$ and $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "solve", and also whether the "two variables each" come in distinct pairs. For example we can easily demonstrate a system of three equations, each involving two variables which has a solution. For example

\begin{align}
x+y=1\\
2x+2y=2\\
x-y=0
\end{align}
which clearly has the solution $x=y=\frac{1}{2}$. Sometimes, however, given a system of three equations in 2 unknowns, you can derive a contradiction. For example, the system
\begin{align}
x+y=1\\
2x+2y=0\\
x-y=0
\end{align}
clearly has no solution because the second equation implies that $x=-y$ and the third implies that $x=y$, which is only possible if $x=y=0$, and this is impossible by the first equation. However, if by "two variables each" you mean six distinct variables overall, then in fact you can always find a solution to such a system, provided it is consistent (unlike the system above). In fact, there are always infinitely many solutions to such a system. Each equation provides a condition which eliminates one variable. So the three equations together reduce the system (involving six unknowns) to a single equation having three variables. Provided the system is consistent, there are infinitely many solutions (to see this, arbitrarily assign values to the first two variables and solve for the third).

Comment: Thanks so much. I understood this and the answer was not too rigorous for someone in high school like myself :).

Comment: How does a condition eliminate one variable though? I dont get exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: Consider the first equation of the first example above. We can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ to yield $y=1-x$. Now in the remaining two equations, we can substitute $1-x$ for $y$, so that the two remaining equations each involve only the single variable $x$. For example, substituting this expression into the third equation yields $x-(1-x)=0$ so that $x=1/2$. I.E. the third equation has eliminated the one remaining variable, leaving 0 variables (i.e. the system has been solved). It follows that, in general, on needs as many equations as there are unknowns to guarantee a *unique* solution.